# How does the BEXTR instruction in x86 work

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

As mentioned in the title, I came across a BEXTR (bit extract) instruction on x86 assembly but I cannot seem to wrap my head around how it works.

After looking online for some time, I even found a supposed C equivalent `(src >> start) & ((1 << len) -1)` which I can't really seem to understand either.

Can anyone explain to me how BEXTR instruction works? How are the bits extracted?

Comment: The formula pretty much says what it does. It extracts `length` bits of the source starting at `start`.

Comment: If you don't understand the shift-and-mask equivalent, maybe the Intel manual's bit-range notation will help: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bextr.  But really you should learn basic bit-manipulation stuff like power-of-2 minus one => bitmask.  See https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks for an introduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A picture might help.  Say the starting bit is 5 and the length is 9.  Then if we have

```
Input : 11010010001110101010110011011010 = 0xd23aacda
                          |-------|
                              \
                               \
                                \
                                 v
                               |-------|
Output: 00000000000000000000000101100110 = 0x00000166
```

The desired block of bits goes to the least significant bits of the output, and the remaining bits of the output become 0.

Answer (score 4):

> How are the bits extracted?

We don't really need to know how the bits are extracted, as that could vary between implementations.  All we need to know is which bits are extracted.

In general, a bit field is a sequential set of bits potentially surrounded by unwanted bits before and after the bit field.  So, the idea is to remove those unwanted bits and move the sequential bits of the bit field of interest to be right justified.

That C formula breaks down into components as follows:

First, `src >> start` shifts bit `start` to bit position 0, effectively right justifying the bit field of interest.  This both moves the bit field of interest into the proper right justified position, as well as eliminating lower bits not of interest (bits of lesser significance, i.e. below the bit field wanted).

What remains to be done is to strip any unwanted bits from above the `length`.  To do this that formula creates what we call a mask.  First, `1<<len` generates a power of two value by shifting 1 (the lowest power of 2) to the left.  So, the number looks like 1 followed by `len` number of zeros (e.g. for len=3, then ..001000).  Subtracting one from a power of 2 makes a mask (e.g. 001000-1=000111) of consecutive 1's that here is `len` bits of 1 in count.  That mask is applied to the shifted result, to remove any unwanted high order bits (bits of higher significance) that are not in the bit field of interest.

---

Another approach in C, would be to shift left to left justify the bit field, then shift that right to right justify the bit field.  This shifting eliminates any unwanted bits both high and low, while leaving the bit field right justified, since that is the last shift.  This approach can also extract both signed and unsigned bit fields, by making the right shift arithmetic vs. logical.