# Why doesn't g++ -O3 optimize this simple bitwise operation

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, bit-manipulation, x86-64

I have this simple function that is called from many inner-most loops.

```
uint16_t getBit(uint16_t val, uint16_t n)
{
    return (val & (1 << n)) >> n;
}
```

This version of the programs takes an average of 3.1 secs to execute.

I then thought to rewrite that function like so:

```
uint16_t getBit(uint16_t val, uint16_t n)
{
    return (val >> n) & 1;
}
```

The second version of the program takes an average 2.9 secs to execute.

Why doesn't GCC optimize this to the same thing with -O3?

Compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/s6fTfo4Ee

Comment: operations are done with `int` (if `int` wider than `uint16_t`)...

Comment: Changing to `int` or `unsigned int` does not change what I found.

Comment: Looks like a missed optimization opportunity.  GCC is open source.  Make the optimization for GCC, submit it in a pull request.

Comment: @Eljay: Much easier said than done, of course.

Comment: Beyond that, [Clang used a neater trick](https://godbolt.org/z/MzshMdzWj), so if you're submitting new optimizations you may as well go all the way.

Comment: Note that if `val` were of type `int` then the two functions would really be different.  In that case, `getBit(-1, 31)` must return `-1`, while `getBit2(-1, 31)` would have to return `1`.  So the optimization depends on keeping track of the fact that `uint16_t val`, when promoted to `int`, is non-negative.

Comment: @harold: GCC emits that same `bt / setc` code if you write it as `return !!(val & (1 << n));` which may be worth considering.

Comment: Modern x86-64 CPUs have an instruction for that : [`BEXTR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208751/how-does-the-bextr-instruction-in-x86-work). It can extract a sequence of several bits from an `uint32_t` value with a given offset+length. AFAIK, there is not 16-bit version though. On recent Intel CPUs the reciprocal throughput is at least 0.5 cycle (2 cycle latency). On AMD Zen1/Zen2 CPUs, it is 0.25 cycle (1 cycle latency), so it is optimal. On AMD Zen3/Zen4, it is 0.5 cycle (1 cycle latency).

Comment: I don't know how you're measuring the time, but maybe what you want is to declare your function static inline.  Not helpful if you need to target an older ansi standard, but think it's in the current.  Gcc likes it in any case.

Comment: Could you add a link to your report on gcc's [bug tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)?